# How to send etherenum to msg.sender in solidity 0.5.0

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ganache

```
mapping(uint => Product) public products;

struct Product {

    uint id;
    string name;
    uint price;
    address payable owner;
    bool purchased;   
}

function purchaseProduct(unit _id) public payable {

    Product memory _product = products[_id];
    address payable _seller = _product.owner;
    address payable _buyer = msg.sender;
}
```

`address(_seller).transfer(msg.value)` works good.
But `msg.sender.transfer(msg.value)` and `address(_buyer).transfer(msg.value)` doesn't work.

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Does your contract's balance is enough to send 3 times msg.value ?

Answer (score 1):

In this block (added line number), msg.value is the amount of ether transferred to the contract when calling function.

At line 1, it has already transferred all the ether to _seller.
Line 2 and 3 will fail because there is no more ether left.

```
1    address(_seller).transfer(msg.value);
2    address(_buyer).transfer(msg.value);
3    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
```

Example:
I call purchaseProduct() function with value of 1 ether.

1. `address(_seller).transfer(msg.value)` transfers 1 ether to `_seller`.
2. `address(_buyer).transfer(msg.value)` transfers 1 ether to `_seller`.
3. `msg.sender.transfer(msg.value)` transfers 1 ether to `_seller`.

It fails because there's only 1 ether.